# Joomla 3 template - module width in wrapper

Tags: php, html, css, joomla

First of all, I'd like to apologize, if this problem already has an answer in stackoverflow.com, it's just that I couldn't think of a way how to google the solution.
Anyway, here's my problem:
I'm working on a Joomla! 3.0.2 website and I have encountered a problem with div width.

I want to have 2 different div-s in my wrapper as so:

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="content"></div>
  <?php if($this->countModules('sidebar')) :?>
     <div class="sidebar"></div>
  <?php endif; ?>
</div>
```

I want the "content" to have 70% width of the wrapper and "sidebar" to have 30%, but only when the sidebar has been selected. If sidebar module is not active, I want the "content" width to be 100% .. my question is - how do i do that? I've tried numerous options in css but so far i have not succeeded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

set a second class to the `content` div if `countModules('sidebar')` is 0 and use css to set styles

SCRIPT

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="content <?php if($this->countModules('sidebar')==0) echo "full"; ?>"></div>
  <?php if($this->countModules('sidebar')) :?>
     <div class="sidebar"></div>
  <?php endif; ?>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.content {
   width:70%;
}

.content.full {
   width:100%;
}

.sidebar {
   width:30%;
}
```

the `.content.full` selector will override the `.content` one.

Comment: Evans - Thank you! Basically this is what I was looking for, I can work with that but I thought I'd let you know, that it works the opposite way .. when I set .content 70% and .content.full 100%, the content is 100% when sidebar is active and 70% when not active.. however, to make this work, I set .content.full 70% and .content 100% - works like a charm

Comment: yea i did the check wrong the if should check that countModules('sidebar') is 0, not more than 0